# Creating a Database Table with the name $email

Tags: mysql, nested, wamp

I want to create a table dynamically on the email name which have to come from SELECT query but it is not working. I already tried `CREATE TABLE ".$email." (Topic varchar(20),Name varchar(20))`;; where email name coming from SELECTquery and saved it in $email variable.

```
'$sql_create="CREATE TABLE (select email from user_info where user_name like '".$user_name."' and password='".$password."') (Topic varchar(20),Name varchar(20))";;'
```

Answer (score 0):

So you do the select and assign the email name to $email so I guess not pure sql but also php ... then... I can't be bothered to create a database and table to extract the table name so I will just assign a value to $email....

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
$email='table_name';
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `{$email}`(Topic varchar(20), Name varchar(20))");
?>
```